# Suspending coroutine function till it receives result and then continue

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm slowly learning `kotlin-coroutines` and want I wanted to start with was simple case where I iterate through list and each time call an API call, wait for response, do with it and then repeat the process every iteration.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
     list.forEach { item ->
          Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration before calling test(): ${item.id}")

          test()

          Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration after calling test(): ${item.id}")
     }
}

suspend fun test(item.id: String) = coroutineScope {
    Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test before receiving response: ${item.id}")

    val apiRepsonse = async {
        repository.doingApiCall() {
            Log.d("TESTING", "response: ${item.id}")
        }
    }.await()

    Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test after receiving response: ${item.id}")
}
```

So, if we imagine, that `list` contains: `{ 10, 15, 25, 35 }` (id's)

I'd want to receive in `logcat` following:

```
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration before calling test(): 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test before receiving response: 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "response: 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test after receiving response: 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration after calling test(): 10")
___________________
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration before calling test(): 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test before receiving response: 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "response: 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test after receiving response: 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration after calling test(): 15")
...
```

**But**, right now I'm getting something like this:

```
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration before calling test(): 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test before receiving response: 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test after receiving response: 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration after calling test(): 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration before calling test(): 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test before receiving response: 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test after receiving response: 15")
Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration after calling test(): 15")

Log.d("TESTING", "response: 10")
Log.d("TESTING", "response: 15")

...
```

Basically, for-each loop moves and does not wait for the API async response. I thought `.await()` is intended for this scenerio, but I might be missing something here as it clearly does not work as I imagined it.

Comment: What is the declared return type of `doingApiCall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
val apiRepsonse = async {
        repository.doingApiCall() {
            Log.d("TESTING", "response: ${item.id}")
        }
    }.await()
```

to

```
val apiRepsonse = async {
        Log.d("TESTING", "Start work in another 'thread'.")
        repository.doingApiCall() {
            Log.d("TESTING", "Finish work in another 'thread'.")
        }
    }.await()
Log.d("TESTING", "response: ${apiRepsonse.id}")
```

That way the value that your await is delivering is actually used.

I think it'll clear up your LogCat confusion.

---

I was trying to work through your problem myself, I have written it up as a test that can be run to be understood:

```
class TestFoo {

    @Test
    fun foo() {
        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            listOf("10", "15").forEach { item ->
                println("TESTING forEach iteration before calling test(): ${item}")

                test(item)

                println("TESTING forEach iteration after calling test(): ${item}")
            }
        }
        while(job.isActive) {
            // wait
        }
    }

    private suspend fun test(item: String) = coroutineScope {
        println("TESTING suspend test before receiving response: ${item}")

        val apiRepsonse = async {
            delay(1000)
            println("TESTING response: ${item}")
            "Hello"
        }.await()

        println("TESTING suspend test after receiving response: ${item}")
    }

}
```

And here is the "LogCat":

[image]

Are you getting different logs because of some threading that is happening inside of `repository.doingApiCall()`?

Comment: `async-await` should be just `withContext`, but you don't need that at all if `doingApiCall` is a suspendable function. Since you don't switch contexts, `async-await` has no effect. If `doingApiCall` is a blocking function, you should wrap in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `repository.doingApiCall()` is not a proper suspend function and is firing off some asynchronous action without suspending the coroutine. It looks like it takes a lambda as a callback, another clue that it is not a suspending function.

And if it were a suspending function, you wouldn't need to dispatch it with `async`.

As an aside, using `async` and immediately calling `await` on it is a more convoluted and less optimized way of using `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` and it also swallows exceptions silently.

Answer (score 0):

Did not test, this should work:

```
// same code here
viewModelScope.launch {
     list.forEach { item ->
          Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration before calling test(): ${item.id}")

          test()

          Log.d("TESTING", "forEach iteration after calling test(): ${item.id}")
     }
}

suspend fun test(item.id: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test before receiving response: ${item.id}")

    repository.doingApiCall() {
        Log.d("TESTING", "response: ${item.id}")
    }

    Log.d("TESTING", "suspend test after receiving response: ${item.id}")
}
```

Two things changed:

- instead of starting new `coroutineScope`, use `withContext()` so it suspends the caller
- inside `withContext()`, you don't need to use `async.await`

Comment: `coroutineScope` *does* suspend the caller. Using `withContext` vs. `async`/`await` won't change the result here aside from letting exceptions bubble up.

Comment: `coroutineScope == withContext(this.coroutineContext)`